# Formula for Determining Cost

Tags: summation, definition

I am trying to put together a formula for determining company costs for certain services in-house. A little background: before I arrived, the company outsourced their IT work. Now that I've been hired, for the past year we have tried to get away from outsourcing the work and bring it in-house, thereby saving annuals costs to the company (we're a non-profit, so any money we can save is great).

I will be presenting my case to move our networking in-house. I want to put together a formulaic presentation to prove this will be cost-beneficial to us. However, I want it to be generic so that, in the future, I can apply this same formula to different aspects. I'm working on the definitions for the formula.

Here's what I've worked out so far. I need to make sure it is all correct.

> When determining to move from an outsourced managed service to an in-house managed service, initial cost must be determined. In determining this cost, the following must be considered to get an accurate budget:
>
> > 1. Cost of hardware/software/devices
> > 2. Cost of labor
> > 3. Initial setup time
>
> For the first item in the list, two variables are required to determine total cost, $T$.
>
> Let $D_n = x_n(y_n)$, $x,y \in \mathbb{R}, n \in \mathbb{Z}$, where $x_n$ is the number of needed items and $y_n$ is the cost of a single item. $n$ denotes which item it is (i.e. if two different items with separate y cost exist, n=1 for the first item, n=2 for the second, and so forth).

Here is one of the lines of text in question, as I think it is either not needed or I'm thinking incorrectly:

> Let $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ and denote the total number of items.

Continuing:

> Example: 
>   For the installation of new routers in a facility, one must order 3 routers and 75 ft. of cabling, requiring 25 ft. for each router. Each router is \$75 and each 25 ft. length of cabling is \$5. Then
>
> $x_1 = 3$
>
> $y_1 = 75$
>
> $D_1 = 3(75) = 225$
>
> It follows that $D_2 = \$15.$
>   Using the summation formula $T = \sum_{n=1}^m(D_n),$
>
> $T = 225 + 15 = \$240.$

I have not written the definitions for Labor and Hours yet because I want to ensure I have correctly written this definition. Once I have correctly defined Cost, the definitions for Labor and Hours follow.

Comment: Companies, even if they are non-profit, should be willing to pay people to do what they can't do for themselves.

Comment: I don't see any math question in here; anyway, it seems that everything you've done is ok.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, that was the point I was making. We can NOW do those things for ourselves because they hired me. Before, they could not.

Comment: @Crostul the math question lies within whether the definition I have given is correct; moreover, would there be a need for $m$ in this case.

Comment: Your wording (or my understanding) of "it follows that $D_2=15$..." sounds incorrect since $D_n$ is a function of $x_n$ alone. Another thing, is that this rather an over complication of  simple product sum!

Comment: @NoChance wouldn't $D_n$ be a function of $x_n(y_n)$? So my logic at the time I wrote that was since $D_1 = x_1(y_1) = 3(75) = 225$, it would follow that $D_2 = x_2(y_2) = 3(5) = 15$. I just took out the math part of it and assumed it based on $D_1$, but there again, it's been awhile since I've written any mathematical definitions or proofs, so my wording could have been wrong.

Comment: It is OK, the wording gave me the impression that there is a dependency.

Comment: Another question I've arrived at is should I define $D$ to be a function of two variables, e.g. $D(x,y)$? If so, would the correct definition of the function be $D_n (x_n , y_n)$ or would $D(x,y)$ suffice?

Answer (score 0):

Looks good to me! The only thing I'd say is that m doesn't denote the total number of items to be purchased but rather the number of different items to be purchased (2 in your example).

Comment: I wrote that wrong. I meant to write the word "different" but it slipped my mind. Thanks!

Comment: @Doctor Gurge no problem! To further elaborate, yes you do need m because you need to first calculate how much you will spend on each type of item and then sum over the totals for each type of item.